# Update just fields I set on update clause using triggers and functions

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-view

I have a function connected with a trigger on a view. View is linked to "my_table" and others table. I wanna update that table through the function. I have 4 fields. But what about if I update just one field, for example contact_name. How can I put just that field on the SET statement and not the 4 fields as in the example below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table
                SET
                    identifier = NEW.identifier,
                    contact_name = NEW.contact_name,
                    contact_phone_number = NEW.contact_phone_number,
                    repair_date = NEW.repair_date,
                WHERE id=OLD.id;
            RETURN NEW;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use dynamic SQL for that. But it doesn't matter. If you update a table, all<sup>1</sup> its fields get copied to the new row by the database even if you don't specify them explicitly.

So unless you might also separately update those fields elsewhere and don't want to overwrite their new values, just set them all and don't worry about it.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Well, except unchanged fields stored out-of-line in TOAST tables*